# Not able to launch the MAC Application that is uploaded For App Store submission

Tags: macos, xamarin.mac

I'm having trouble with a Mac App Store submission

I have an Application Developed in Xamarin.Forms
I release the App from Visual Studio for MAC in **Release** mode
When I Install the package manually in my MAC system It is working perfect.
But when i upload the same package to AppleStore same is rejected With reason as

**Binary Rejected

Guideline 2.3 - Performance Your app does not achieve the core functionality described in your marketing materials or release notes.

Specifically, App does not launch from Finder. App icon momentarily appears on Dock but quit itself before being launched.**

Here are the detail of my Visual Studio and MAC Signing
[Detail of Visual Studio for MAC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoHLK.jpg)

[MAC Signing detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiCaG.jpg)

**Crash Report of this is as below**

Process:               MYApp [3341]

Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/*/MYApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MYApp

Version:               ???

Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)

Parent Process:        ??? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoHLK.jpg)

Responsible:           MYApp [3341]

User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-02-01 12:51:57.589 +0530

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)

Report Version:        12

Anonymous UUID:        4C4421D7-C0F8-0B8D-8B82-A6E78F50AE60

Time Awake Since Boot: 9000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)

Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

Comment: have you got the crash report if it is generated?

Comment: @vikramsingh : Crash Report detail is Edited in Post

Answer (score 1):

Review the official doc on the reason behind "EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)" and how to manually sign your app.

#### Q:  When I run my Mac app, it crashes immediately, and the crash log says Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid). What is going on here?

> A: The crash log indicates that your app is signed with your Mac App Store distribution identity, with the certificate’s Subject Common Name starting with “3rd Party Mac Developer Application.” Mac apps signed this way can no longer be run directly. Here’s the background on this.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1884/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015141